# Java - Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'double' to 'double'

Tags: java, arrays, double, instanceof

While writing code to check the datatype of entries in a Java 11 array, I came across a compile-time error which I can't seem to find anywhere on Google or SO. I'm using JetBrains's IntelliJ IDEA, and the editor is giving me the error **"Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'double' to 'double'."** for the second line in the following MWE (that is, put inside a `main` method etc.):

```
double[] arr = new double[] {0.1, 0.2};
boolean result = arr[0] instanceof double;
```

I don't really get what's wrong here. Isn't `instanceof` exactly analogous to Python's `isinstance`? New to Java (not to Python nor the Java derivative Processing), so this baffles me.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `instanceof` does not work with primitive data types. Only objects.

Comment: What would be the point? Primitives don't support inheritance.

Comment: @azurefrog: Turning the second line into `boolean result = Double.class.isInstance(arr[0]);` seems to work! Also, if you don't mind me following up: isn't my IDE incorrect in saying a `double` can't be cast to a `double`? I recall that that would show up greyed-out in IntelliJ (since it'd be redundant), but certainly not impossible ...